# Using autoSettings in play.Project.playScalaSettings

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I am using Play 2.2 with SBT 0.13. SBT 0.13 introduced a new feature called autoSettings (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#control-over-automatically-added-settings) that I have been using with my project definition, such as:

lazy val projectA = Project(id="projectA", base=file("."))
.autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../common.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)

However I am struggling to use this with Play project. When I use it with Play project, I get error:

error: value autoSettings is not a member of Seq[sbt.Setting[_]]

My Play project definition is:

play.Project.playScalaSettings.autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../common.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)

Am I not using it correctly with Play project or is this not yet supported in Play project?

Answer (score 1):

Add on top of build.sbt:

```
import AddSettings._
```

Add in build.sbt:

```
lazy val main = Project(id="main", base=file(".")).autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../common.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)
```

Or put it all in project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import AddSettings._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val main = Project(id="main", base=file(".")).autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../common.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)
}
```

or you write it this style in build.sbt:

```
import AddSettings._

name := "so1"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache
)

lazy val main = Project(id="main", base=file(".")).settings(play.Project.playScalaSettings:_*).autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../common.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)
```

Another possible approach is to create a Build.scala (like in Play 2.1) make the settings there to a play.Project(appName, ...) that is a real SBT project.

Comment: This is what I currently have. My question is how do I use autoSettings with Play project, especially together with the play.Project.playScalaSettings in Play 2.2.

Comment: Look into the source of play.Project, in Play 2.2 you don't create a new project like in 2.1, you just apply settings. So you don't have any project to call the method autoSettings. play.Project ist just in your case a misleading name.

Comment: I added an alternative approach where the play settings are only applied to the project.

Comment: Here is the source code for play.Project, there you can see, that you only apply settings and no explicit project creation is done: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.0/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/Project.scala#L49

Comment: Thanks so much on looking into this. Yes, after looking the source, it makes complete sense to put that in the settings.